# For Loop Eval Expression can't convert boolean to string

Tags: sql, ssis

I want to iterate thru a data flow several times based on a date being less than todays date, where i gradullay change that date to be today's date via an assign expression in the for loop container, however I'm having problems.

I have setup the initial expression, and the Assign Expression by using project params (user variables), but can't get past the Eval expression error if keeping the output as boolean, and yet changing it to a string, as shown, creates an error in the For Loop container itself where it expects a Boolean value.

Assign Expression:

```
REPLACE((DT_WSTR, 10)(DT_DBDATE)DATEADD( "day", 1, @[$Project::StartDate]  ),"-","")
```

Init Expression:

```
REPLACE((DT_WSTR, 10)(DT_DBDATE) @[$Project::StartDate] ,"-","")
```

Eval Expression:

```
@[$Project::StartDate] < getdate() ? "Y":"N"
```

If I change the Eval Expression to @[$Project::StartDate] < getdate() I get an error in the Expression Builder, can't convert boolean to string

[image]

Comment: Remember to post the expressions as text so it's easier to edit.

Comment: What data type is Startdate? And why are you converting dates to string? You shouldn't if you want to compare against `getdate()`

Comment: The startdate is datetime. The only reason I'm converting the result to a string is that All the expressions in the builder appear to require the Result as a string type. If I keep it as a date, I get the error, error converting date to string in the expression builder.

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1970.ssis-for-loop-container.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Create a user variable of type `DateTime` (called `YourNewDatetimeVariable` in this example), then use these expressions:

Init Expression:

```
@[User::YourNewDatetimeVariable] = @[$Project::StartDate]
```

Eval Expression:

```
@[User::YourNewDatetimeVariable] < GETDATE()
```

Assign Expression:

```
@[User::YourNewDatetimeVariable] = DATEADD("d", 1,  @[User::YourNewDatetimeVariable])
```

Comment: Clearly I'm not seeing the wood thru the trees, for if I do that i get an error in that the expression build says, can't convert boolean to string

Comment: @user9930055 edited, try updating your expressions so they don't validate against string data types.

Comment: Thanks for your perseverance here. Ok I have changed startdate and Newstartdate to be user variables, as project params are read only once execution begins, didn't know that.... but now i'm getting the error, error converting datetime to string, when I try to click OK on the InitExpression having changed it to : @[User::NewStartDate]= @[User::StartDate]

Comment: @user9930055 it seems that one of your variables isn't datetime, make sure that either both are datetimes or that you correctly convert the string to datetime before assigning

Comment: Thanks. I was massively over complicating. I was using macro sub, within the Expression builders, using C escape characters \" for the quotation marks... etc, etc.... Cheers for your help

Comment: @user9930055 Glad you could solve it. Make sure next time to post your complete situation and don't leave anything outside!